# Redirect only one URL with parameter

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect URL, for example:

```
www.mydomain.com/category/sub-category/product?page=shop.ask&flypage=flypage.tpl&product_id=181&category_id=34
```

To:

```
www.mydomain.com/category/sub-category/good-product.html
```

I have a multiple URLs with parameters that need to be redirected to only one or couple of URLs, can you help me, I used Google for hours.

I was try this code at `.htaccess`:

```
redirect 301 /category/sub-category/product?page=shop.ask&flypage=flypage.tpl&product_id=181&category_id=34 www.mydomain.com/category/sub-category/good-product.html
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't match against the query string in a `Redirect` directive. You'll need to use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=shop.ask&flypage=flypage.tpl&product_id=181&category_id=34$
RewriteRule ^category/sub-category/product$ /category/sub-category/good-product.html? [L,R=301]
```